# How can i get last row with mixed data and blank cells from sheet to another one

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

[How can i get last row with mixed data and blank cells from sheet to another one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQlU6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can get column height:

```
function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()){ rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
  //const h = Utilities.formatString('col: %s len: %s', col, rcA.length - s);
  //Logger.log(h);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(h).setWidth(150).setHeight(100), 'Col Length')
}
```